# NSString Copy Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I have an app that leverages the TouchJSON objective-C library and I'm running the Instruments profiler for memory leaks and getting a leak in that source that I can't figure out how to fix.  I should mention that I'm fairly new to Cocoa and objective-C.  Instruments is showing that the leak occurs in a method with the following signature:

```
- (BOOL)scanJSONStringConstant:(NSString **)outStringConstant error:(NSError **)outError
```

...and the leak is specifically occurring in this block of code:

```
if (self.options & kJSONScannerOptions_MutableLeaves)
{
     *outStringConstant = [theString autorelease];
}
else
{
    *outStringConstant = [[theString copy] autorelease];   //LEAK IS HAPPENING HERE
    [theString release];
}
```

I've tried a variety of fixes to try and get rid of the leak but with no success.  Can someone please educate me on:

1)  Why this is a leak

...and...

2)  How to fix it

I'm familiar with the rudiments of objective-C memory management ("If you alloc, copy, or new...release is up to you") so I don't need a whole primer on the basics - just some insight as to why this is leaking.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:  Attaching image of debug info.
[image: Debug Info]

Comment: What was retain count of `outStringConstant` before this code block?

Comment: I do an NSLog(@"%@", [*outStringConstant retainCount]); and get (null) in the console.  Does this have something to do with the fact that the outStringConstant is being defined as (NSString **) instead of (NSString *)?

Comment: You shouldn't look into retainCount at all. It is misleading at best. (You will need to use %d for an integer, but then again - don't!)

Answer (score 3):

What Instruments is telling you isn't that the leak occurred at that line, instead it's telling you that the object created at that line was leaked.

I would look again at the client code that uses the scanJSONStringConstant method and review its memory management.  Is there a logical flow where it may miss a release call on the outStringConstant pointer?

Answer (score 1):

change this line `*outStringConstant = [[theString copy] autorelease];`

TO

```
if(*outStringConstant)
   [*outStringConstant release];

*outStringConstant = [NSString stringWithString:theString];
[theString release];
```